# How can I use json Data inside of my component state invalid when trying to use said data inside a variable?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, highcharts, react-redux

I am trying to take the data I place into my state and then use portions of said data in the config variable so I can then render this data onto highCharts. However, I keep getting errors saying that "Cannot read property 'SeriesDates' of undefined, and etc for any other data from my json call. However, when I console log the state, the data is clearly in the state. The question is why can't I use it inside the config variable and how do I get it as values inside the variable? I am able to use data from my redux state easily ({this.props.stock.Name}) but the same is not true for the output from my json call.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import ReactHighcharts from 'react-highcharts';

class StockChart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {chart: []};
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.ChartData();
  }

  ChartData() {
    return $.getJSON(`http://dev.markitondemand.com/MODApis/Api/Timeseries/json?symbol=${this.props.stock.Symbol}`)
      .then((data) => {
        var raw = JSON.stringify(data);
        var json = JSON.parse(raw);
        this.setState({ chart: json });
        console.log(this.state);
      });
  }

  render() {

    const config = {
      title: {
          text: `${this.props.stock.Name}`,
          x: -20 //center
      },
      subtitle: {
          text: `${this.props.stock.Symbol}`,
          x: -20
      },
      xAxis: {
          categories: `${this.state.chart.Data.SeriesDates}`
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Price'
          },
          plotLines: [{
              value: 0,
              width: 1,
              color: '#808080'
          }]
      },
      tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '$'
      },
      series: [{

          name: 'AAPL',
          data: `${this.state.chart.Data.close.values}`
      }]
    };

    if (!this.props.stock) {
      return <div></div>
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <ReactHighcharts config={config}></ReactHighcharts>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    stock: state.selectedStock
  };
}
```

Comment: Since you're already using Redux, I would move your chart data to your  global Redux state, so your component isn't concerned with the specifics of how to fetch data.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a close look into your code you are setting state after the component is mount. According to the react component [lifecycle](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) componentDidMount triggers after the first render. so at the time of render you will have empty chart state. i.e. `this.state.chart.Data = undefined`. so your code `this.state.chart.Data.SeriesDates` will throw the above error.

Note: since you are fetching data from server even though you put logic in componentWillMount it will through same error because fetching data from server takes time.

There could be two ways to solve the problem:

1. To set the initial state to some default values referring to the format of data that is returned

   `this.state = {chart: {
      Data: {
       SeriesData: {},
       close: {},
       ...
      }
    }
   };`

OR 
2. check for undefined in the render method.

```
    const Data = this.state.chart.Data;
    if(Data){
    const config = {
      title: {
          text: `${this.props.stock.Name}`,
          x: -20 //center
      },
      subtitle: {
          text: `${this.props.stock.Symbol}`,
          x: -20
      },
      xAxis: {
          categories: `${this.state.chart.Data.SeriesDates}`
      },
      yAxis: {
          title: {
              text: 'Price'
          },
          plotLines: [{
              value: 0,
              width: 1,
              color: '#808080'
          }]
      },
      tooltip: {
          valueSuffix: '$'
      },
      series: [{

          name: 'AAPL',
          data: `${this.state.chart.Data.close.values}`
      }]
    };
    }
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Although your answer is correct, just to be clear, the application would fail, if he instead tried to move the fetching to a function before `render` in the react lifecycle, since he's retrieving the data asynchronously. So the lifecycle is really irrelevant in this case.

Comment: Normally Data fetching are done in componentWillMount because it is triggered before render. yeah its seems irrelevant in this case, so we will have to go through any of the 2 solution.

Comment: Yes and no. Moving it to `componentWillMount` wouldn't really matter, since the data fetching is asynchronous and the call to `this.setState` would most likely still end up being called after the first render anyways. So yes, your solutions would be only way to solve it.